# How long an Azure' web role can stay active?

Tags: upload, azure, azure-sql-database

My cloud application (web role) uploads over 5000 records into SQL Azure.
The total time for this process takes about 15-19 minutes on my development machine.
Once, I deploy to the Cloud and try again, it fails after 10 - 12 minutes without any error message.

My guess is that the web role times out after certain period of time. Is there a setting for this?

Comment: This may be due to throttling.

Comment: Can you please clarify what, exactly, times out? Is it the deployment to the cloud, or the operation itself? Web roles, once started, don't have time-out or get throttled, except by cpu utilization, bandwidth, etc. as defined by your virtual machine size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your webrole doesn't time out.

SQL Azure can time out and also your connection can be killed.

Some reasons for Connection Termination:

- Sessions consuming greater than one million locks are terminated.
- Transactions with a log file size > 1 GB are terminated.
- The distance from the first or oldest active transaction log sequence number (LSN) to the tail of the log (current LSN) cannot exceed 20% of the size of the log file.
- If a transaction locks a resource required by an underlying system operation for more than 20 seconds, it is terminated.
- When a session uses more than 5 GB of tempdb space (= 655,360 pages), the session is terminated.
- When there is memory contention, sessions consuming greater than 16-megabyte (MB) for more than 20 seconds are terminated in the descending order of time the resource has been held, such as the oldest session is terminated first.
- A database will be read-only when it reaches its maximum database size. Transactions attempting to updates or inserts will be terminated when this happens.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/sql-azure-connection-management-in-sql-azure.aspx#Reasons

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest you page your upload? Even if it's just to build the record set in memory (cache/queue/table/blob store rather) and then execute against SQL.

At the very least it'll allow you to isolate where the issue is.